# Has anybody tried to install Liferay Portal CE on HP-UX?

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6, hp-ux

I have developed portal based on Liferay Portal CE 6.1.1ga2 (bundled version with tomcat 7.0.27). It worked fine on my windows machine with java x64 version 1.6.0_31 and on linux server with Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga) and java x64 version 1.6.0_29. Now I have to install portal to HP Superdome 2 with HP-UX. I am not administrator of that server, but I know last version of java 6 from HP-UX repositories and HP-UX OS are installed. My portal doesn't start on server. I also tried to install clean bundled version of Liferay Portal 6.1.1ga2, 6.1.2ga3 (tomcat 7.0.40), 6.2.0ga1 (tomcat 7.0.42). The newest version 6.2.0 I tried to run with java 6 and java 7. I tried to install 6.1.1ga2 from WAR file to tomcat server from HP-UX repositories, but it didn't help. Everywhere I have the same error message.

The log file catalina.out has size 9.3 MB and contains 48000 lines after one start.
Main part

```
....
Jan 14, 2014 6:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
06:09:55,229 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:71] Determine dialect for HSQL Database Engine 2
06:09:55,241 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:86] Liferay is configured to use Hypersonic as its database. Do NOT use Hypersonic in production. Hypersonic is an embedded database useful for development and demo'ing purposes. The database settings can be changed in portal-ext.properties.
06:09:55,312 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:136] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
06:10:40,958 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][ContextLoader:206] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ResourceActionsUtil' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ResourceActionsImpl#2264e6' of type [com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ResourceActionsImpl] while setting bean property 'resourceActions'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ResourceActionsImpl#2264e6' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortletLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.AccountLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.AccountService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.AddressLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.AddressService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.BackgroundTaskLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.BackgroundTaskService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.BrowserTrackerLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ClassNameLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ClassNameService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ClusterGroupLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.CMISRepositoryLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ContactLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ContactService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.CountryService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.EmailAddressLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.EmailAddressService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.GroupService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ImageLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ImageService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceHelper' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourcePermissionLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutBranchLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutBranchService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
...
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.CounterPersistence' defined in class path resource [META-INF/counter-spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

And many-many such messages with "error creating bean with name" ending with

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I deployed to tomcat simple servlet application and spring "hello world" application, they work fine.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was obvious. Use -Xss512k in setenv.sh to increase thread stack size